# How to forbid to accept a offer for car that has already been accepted Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I try the detail to explain the code. The seller receives more offer for his car. When he accepts a certain offer for a particular car, I want to forbid him to accept other offers again for same car. 
Example. The seller accepted the offer id. 2, price 3000, car_id 4.
Seller can no longer accept offer id.3 or 4 or 5, price 4000, car_id 4.
Look my code and database

```
   public function accept($id){
        $userId =  Auth::user();
        $offerId = Offer::with('user')->find($id);
        if(!$offerId){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Oooops this offer does not exist or is currently unavailable'
            ]);
        }
        if($offerId->accepted === 1){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Oooops this offer is already accepted'
            ]);
        }

     $res =   DB::table('offers')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update(['accepted' => 1]);
     if(!$res){
         return response()->json([
             'message' => 'Ooooops the offer is already accepted'
         ]);
     }
        Mail::to($offerId->user->email)->send(new AcceptOffer());
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully accepted offer',
            'offer' => $id
        ]);

    }
```

My table Offer with manipulate with offer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaySx.jpg

Relation between Offer and Car and User:

Car:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function offer() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

Offer:

```
public function car() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Car');
}
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User:

```
public function cars(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Car');
}
public function offers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simple check, if there is some offer for that specific car allready accepted.

```
$acceptedCount = Offer::where('car_id', $offerId->car_id)->where('accepted', 1)->count(); 
if($acceptedCount > 0){
    return response()->json([
         'message' => 'Another offer for this car was already accepted'
     ]);
}
```

Comment: This is work fine but this function is run over my message 'message' => 'Oooops this offer is already accepted'
how to return that? 
If user click on same offer got message above, but if click on another offer of same car got message 'Another offer for this car was already accepted'

Comment: Well then just exclude current offer: `$acceptedCount = Offer::where('car_id', $offerId->car_id)->where('accepted', 1)->where('id', '!=', $offerId->id)->count();`

Comment: Only one think. 
Can you explain me what happened in this code? 
count() what ? :)

Comment: You count number of Offers, which have same car_id (same value in database in column `car_id`) as $offerId (current offer, which you want to accept) and also are accepted (column `accepted` is set to `1`). But you exclude current offer (by its ID).